How to create a CreateQueryBuilder for Postgresql and Symfony
I have a Users entity that contains a roles field. The field is defined as follows:
/**
* @var list<string> The user roles     
*/
#[ORM\Column]     
private array $roles = [];

I am using Symfony and a Postgresql database. In database field roles is converted to type json
I want to create a custom query that extracts all the 'Users' that have one of these two roles: "ROLE_ADMIN" and "ROLE_ADMIN_DELEGATION".
How could I do it?
If I do the query directly in the database:
SELECT u.* FROM users u WHERE u.roles::jsonb @> '"ROLE_ADMIN"' OR u.roles::jsonb @> '"ROLE_ADMIN_DELEGATION"';
It works perfectly. But when trying to transform it into "doctrine" language it does not return any elements
public function findAdministrators(int $offset): Paginator
{        
    $roles = ["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_ADMIN_DELEGATION"];
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $orWhere = [];
    $parameters = [];

    foreach ($roles as $i => $rol) {
        $parameterName = 'rol' . $i;
        $orWhere[] = 'JSON_CONTAINS(u.roles, :' . $parameterName . ')';
        $parameters[$parameterName] = $rol;
    }

    $qb->where(implode(' OR ', $orWhere))
        ->setParameters(new ArrayCollection($parameters))  // Fix here
        ->setMaxResults(self::MEMBERS_PER_PAGE)
        ->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->getQuery()
    ;

    return new Paginator($qb);
}


Do you use a doctrine extension ? doctrine does not support JSON_CONTAINS natively

Hello, @DylanKAS
Do you mean beberlei/doctrineextensions?
My composer.json:
"require": {         ...         "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.5",         "doctrine/dbal": "^3",         "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.12",         "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",         "doctrine/orm": "^3.2",         ...

Yeah this kind of library, in your case https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions only has JSON_CONTAINS for MySql

Ah, well.
She was expecting an error message, but it just doesn't return any results.
Do you know of any "doctrine extension" that replaces that function for Postgresql?
